# SweetAlert2 confirmar envío de datos al controlador para eliminar registro, jsf, mvc, h: commandButton type = "submit" no primefaces 2

Tags: javascript, mvc, jsf, sweetalert, sweetalert2

tengo un problema al momento de mostrar una alerta de **SweetAlert2**, y es que la alerta dura menos de un segundo y enviar los datos al controlador y la vista se recarga mostrando que se eliminó el registro.

El procedimiento normal sin confirmaciones, es que al dar clic al botón de eliminar del registro, los datos se envían al controlador y se eliminan dicho registro, luego retorna a la vista con la lista, mostrando que se efectúa la eliminación.

Busco que antes de que se envíen los datos al controlador, con precisión una alerta pidiendo la confirmación de la acción, algo como el confirmar de **`javascript`** pero con los estilos de **SweetAlert2**.

**Vista**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <head>
        <title>Lista</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Views/css/fonts.css" />
    </head>
    <body style="padding: 30px;">
        <f:view>
            <h:form id="form">
                <h1><h:outputText value="List"/></h1>
                <h:dataTable id="table" class="responsive-table" value="#{usuarioControlador.consultarTodos()}" var="item">
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="ID"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.idUsuario}"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Cedula"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.cedulaUsuario}"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Nombre"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.nombreUsuario}"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Primer Apellido"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.primerApellidoUsuario}"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Email"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.emailUsuario}"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Tipo de Usuario"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.tipoUsuario.tipoUsuario}"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>  
                        <h:commandLink class="btn-small yellow darken-1" action="#{usuarioControlador.preActualizar(item)}">
                            <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                        </h:commandLink>
                        <h:commandButton class="btn-small red darken-1" action="#{usuarioControlador.eliminar(item)}" value="Borrar" onclick="swalConfirm()"/>
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
            </h:form>
        </f:view>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8.18.1/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"/>
        <script src="../Views/js/swal.js"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
function swalConfirm() {
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
        }
    });
}
```

**Controlador**:

```
public String eliminar(Usuario eliminar) {
    usuarioFacade.remove(eliminar);
    return "list";
}
```

Ya he intentado con **`event.preventDefault();`** y cuando se presiona el botón de confirmación **`$("#form").submit();`** y al momento de dar clic en confirmar se recarga la vista pero no se elimina el registro y con puntos de interrupción vi que no entra al controlador.

Gracias por la ayuda.

---

Anexo **screenshot** de la tabla(normalmente se abre en un **iframe** al dar consultar usuarios):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y el código que va dentro de la confirmación de Sweetalert ???

Comment: Hola @FRANCISCO J. BLANCO, lo único que había dentro del "if" del SweetAlert2, era otra alerta que aparecía diciendo que se eliminó correctamente, la cual por ahora no necesito que aparezca.

Comment: Pero es que necesias agregar el codigo que elimina dentro de la confirmación al dar aceptar, y cuando elimine hay si muestras la otra alerta

Comment: Lo que pasa es que en jsf al dar click al botón de tipo submit (h:commandButton), el action lleva el registro hacia el controlador y al método que en este caso es el de eliminar registro, entonces, al ser de tipo submit la alerta aparece solo por un segundo y desaparece, por lo tanto el registro se elimina antes de poder confirmar la acción (no funciona igual que el "confirm" de javascript y es lo que necesito que suceda)